# Oracle comparing $EXP$ with $UP$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, oracles, exp-time-algorithms, relativization

[Heller](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0213045) (Theorem 6) gave an oracle relative to which $NP=EXP$, and [Homer & Selman](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(92)90023-C) gave an oracle relative to which $P=UP$ and $\Sigma_2^P=EXP$.

[Beigel, Buhrman, Fortnow](http://doi.org/10.1145/276698.276737) ([freely available author's version](http://papers.fortnow.com/files/newiso.pdf)) gave an oracle in which $P=\oplus P$ and $NP=EXP$ holds.

> 1. Is there an oracle that gives $P\neq UP=coUP=NP=coNP=\oplus P=EXP$?
> 2. Is there an oracle that gives $P=UP=coUP\neq NP=coNP=\oplus P=EXP$?

Or is it known $UP\neq EXP$ unconditionally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathsf{UP} \neq \mathsf{EXP}$ is open. A UP-generic oracle* should make $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{UP} = \mathsf{EXP}$, and since $\mathsf{UP} \subseteq \mathsf{\oplus P} \subseteq \mathsf{EXP}$ relative to any oracle, this should resolve 1. (I say "should" because I haven't checked all the details...)

*UP-generic oracles are discussed, for example, by [Fenner-Fortnow-Kurtz-Li](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0890-5401(03)00018-X) ([author's freely available version](http://papers.fortnow.com/files/obt.pdf)) and also (shameless self plug) a quick tutorial in Section 5.1 [here](http://doi.org/10.1016/j.ic.2011.01.006) ([author's free version](http://lance.fortnow.com/papers/files/equiv.pdf))

Comment: Since your asnwer was earlier I will accept your answer.

Comment: But what is an UP generic oracle?

Answer (score 7):

The quoted Beigel, Buhrman, and Fortnow paper gives a solution to 2 in Theorem 1.8: there is an oracle relative to which $\mathrm{P=Mod_3P}$ (which implies $\mathrm{P=UP}$), and $\mathrm{\oplus P=NP=EXP}$ (which, together with the first equality, actually implies $\mathrm{EXP=ZPP}$).

Comment: In this case can it also hold $P\neq P^{UP}=NP$?